# selecting count of register users from every month in year, But changing value of timestamp gives incorrect count

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi Have written a query for taking count of register users of all months in a year

```
SELECT MONTH(c1.created_on) AS MONTH, 
     (SELECT COUNT(c2.id)
      FROM register AS c2
       WHERE c2.created_on <= (DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(c1.created_on,
                                                        INTERVAL 1 MONTH),'%Y-%m-01'))) 
       AS registeruser
FROM (SELECT 3 AS mon UNION 
  SELECT 4 AS mon UNION 
  SELECT 5 AS mon
 ) AS m LEFT JOIN
 register AS c1
 ON  MONTH(c1.created_on) = m.mon
GROUP BY MONTH(c1.created_on)
```

So created_on column datatype is DateTime and default value i have set is CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, So when I register a user, current month is april and i add 4 values after that i change month of 1 user to march and execute the query it gives me count as 
for Month April as 4 and march as 1 .
Here I am facing the problem for April still it giving me 4 which should be 3
[image]
[image]

Here in image, I have changed the data, but looking at it will understand the month of April the count it is showing as 4, this only happens when i change the timestamp after added record

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query does not count how many users registered each month.
It counts how many registered up to that month, because the condition is:

```
WHERE c2.created_on <= DATE_FORMAT(.....
```

You should group by `m.mon` and not by `MONTH(c1.created_on)` because `MONTH(c1.created_on)` may be `null` if the month does not exist and there is no need for the subquery:

```
SELECT 
  m.mon AS MONTH, 
  COUNT(c1.created_on) AS registeruser
FROM (
  SELECT 3 AS mon UNION 
  SELECT 4 AS mon UNION 
  SELECT 5 AS mon
 ) AS m 
LEFT JOIN register AS c1
ON  MONTH(c1.created_on) = m.mon
GROUP BY m.mon
```

Comment: Note that this query works for dates of one year. If you have dates of multiple years and you want to check for 2020 you should change the ON clause to: `ON  MONTH(c1.created_on) = m.mon AND YEAR(c1.created_on) = 2020`